# Can't acces error field from error response in axios (difference with devtools)

Tags: javascript, axios

I catch error with axios and the response that I look up in developer tools is as follows:

```
apiName: null
error: "Cannot send package."
errors: null
message: "Conflict"
path: "/api/package/123"
status: 409
timestamp: "2020-04-28T10:11:11.668+0000"
```

I want to access field error with "Cannot send package." value but whatever I do I can't. When I console.log in my catch statement I get:

```
error.response.status:  409
error.response.data.error:  undefined
error.message:  Request failed with status code 409
error.error:  undefined
error.response.data:  Blob {size: 178, type: "application/json"}
error.response.headers:  {cache-control: "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", content-type: "application/json", expires: "0", pragma: "no-cache"}
```

Is there a way to access error field? How this could be done? `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error))` didn't help as well.

The problem could be that this is a POST request to get a PDF file, so the config sent is:

```
   const config = {
    responseType: 'blob',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/pdf, application/json',
    },
  };
```

Comment: Can you post the response headers? is Content-type set to "application/json"? Can you add the axios code you're using?

Comment: what about error.response.data.message?

Comment: error.response.data.message:  undefined

Comment: @leonardfactory yes content-type is set to application/json, I posted what is the output of response headers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `responseType: 'blob'`, but this applies to errors too. Reading the blob back to a JSON should work:

```js
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function() {
    const data = JSON.parse(this.result);
    // ...
};
reader.readAsText(error.response.data);
```

This issue is tracked on axios https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/815#issuecomment-453963910, where you can find even an interceptor to transform automatically the response from the blob back to a json in case of an error.

Comment: Yes, and you can wrap it in a Promise to make it easier to work with.

Comment: The issue is that this is a huge app already and we have custom API calls methods for GET, POST etc. Here we just catch error, which consists of the things I put in my question. Can this just be done her in onError where we catch error?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't get the question correctly. You can do this where you need the error, you don't need to convert it upfront.

Comment: How this can be done when we just have it like this: onError: error => ..........., Here we usually put it to redux store, and we need it as normal response not a blob type.

Comment: You can use the interceptor in the issue comment I linked you in the answer, in this case. It will make transparent to your application the blob error handling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212693/discussion-between-jake-ferguson-and-leonardfactory).

Answer (score 0):

You can handle that in the catch block of you request something like this:

```
axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    // can add breakpoints here to observe the error object
    console.log(error.response && error.response.data);
  })
```

If you try to put some breakpoints in catch block, you can hover and see the structure of the error object.

For reference, you can see the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)